# Server side php script not working in Xampp

Tags: php, html

I tried to run a simple program that will from an html form, collect the name and sex of the user and using the server side script (php) will print out the name and sex entered. this is my html and php code below, I am running xampp control panel version 3.2.1. When I run it from the browser with http://localhost:8080/xampp/test.html, the page goes to http://localhost:8080/xampp/test.php but the page is blank. the php file is test.php and the html file is test.html

HTML

```
<html>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
<p>
Name:
<input type="text" name="fname" id="idone"/>
</p>
<p>
Sex:
<input type="text" name="sex" id="idtwo"/>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" id="submit"/>

</form>

</html>

php code

<?php
//if the name field is filled in
if(isset($_POST['idone']))
{
$name=$_POST['idone'];
$sex=$_POST['idtwo'];
printf("hello %s, you are a %s",$name,$sex);
}

?>
```

Comment: maybe try http://localhost/test.php and name your file test.php

Comment: the php file is already named test.php, and the html file is named test.html

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: do you have any .htaccess running?

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not properly referencing the form inputs from POST data in php.
The objects name in `$_POST` are those from `name` attribute so the correct code in your case will be:

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
// make sure you are properly escaping theese values,
// when you will be dealing with dbs or files
$name=$_POST['fname'];
$sex=$_POST['sex'];
}
```

`<input type="text" name="fname" id="idone"/>`
In this case the `id` attrib (`idone`) in html would be used ONLY for CSS.
It is not POSTed to the server back, so PHP **does not** see it

Comment: ID attributes are not only used for CSS. They are also used for JS, HTML (e.g. the `for` attribute of the `label` element) and for other tools that manipulate the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Servers do not see ids from the html - its for js and css.
Because of that you need to use the `name` parameter.
Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP needs to reference the input field names not the ids. So

```
<?php
//if the name field is filled in

if(isset($_POST['fname'])) {
    $name=$_POST['fname'];
    $sex=$_POST['sex'];
    printf("hello %s, you are a %s",$name,$sex);
}

?>
```